# css accordion with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I found a cool accordion sample online. I copied all of the code to an html file, not sure why it is still not displaying correctly, I have added the js and css code but it still does not display correctly. The menu supposed to already be in "collapsed" position and the color supposed to be black. Does anyone see what could be the issue?

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $this = $(this);

                if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
                    $this.next().removeClass('show');
                    $this.next().slideUp(350);
                } else {
                    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
                    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
                    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
                    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
 * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: inherit;
        }
        p {
            font-size: 1.1em;
            margin: 1em 0;
        }
        .description {
            margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
        }
        body {
            width: 40%;
            min-width: 300px;
            max-width: 400px;
            margin: 1.5em auto;
            color: #333;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 2.5em;
        }
        ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            .inner {
                padding-left: 1em;
                overflow: hidden;
                display: none;
                &.show {
                    /*display: block;*/
                }
            }
            li {
                margin: .5em 0;
                a.toggle {
                    width: 100%;
                    display: block;
                    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
                    color: #fefefe;
                    padding: .75em;
                    border-radius: 0.15em;
                    transition: background .3s ease;
                    &: hover {
                        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 
</head>

<body>
    <h1>A Cool Accordion</h1>

    <p class="description">
        You could simply toggle the .show class (if display: block is uncommented in the CSS) in JavaScript, but you'll lose the animation.
    </p>

    <ul class="accordion">
      <li>
            <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Plan It</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Recieve Ur</a>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Cook It</a>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>
                            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Stew It</a>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>
                            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Create It</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li>Option 1</li>
                <li>Option 2</li>
                <li>Option 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Deliver It</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner</a>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner #2</a>
                    <div class="inner">
                        <p>
                            Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>Option 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Measure It</a>
            <ul class="inner">
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="toggle">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
                    <ul class="inner">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="toggle">Another nested element</a>
                            <div class="inner">
                                <p>
                                    As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>Option 2</li>

                <li>Option 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were using SCSS in the example. When transposed to pure CSS, it works correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.toggle').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
      $this.next().removeClass('show');
      $this.next().slideUp(350);
    } else {
      $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
      $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
      $this.next().toggleClass('show');
      $this.next().slideToggle(350);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

body {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  color: #333;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}


.inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

.inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}

a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}

a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|Open+Sans:300,400,600">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <h1>A Cool Accordion</h1>

  <p class="description">
    You could simply toggle the .show class (if display: block is uncommented in the CSS) in JavaScript, but you'll lose the animation.
  </p>

  <ul class="accordion">
    <li>
      <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Plan It</a>
      <ul class="inner">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Recieve Ur</a>
          <div class="inner">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
              blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Cook It</a>
          <div class="inner">
            <p>
              Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Stew It</a>
          <div class="inner">
            <p>
              Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Create It</a>
      <ul class="inner">
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Deliver It</a>
      <ul class="inner">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner</a>
          <div class="inner">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
              blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Open Inner #2</a>
          <div class="inner">
            <p>
              Children will automatically close upon closing its parent.
            </p>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li>Option 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="toggle" href="javascript:void(0);">Measure It</a>
      <ul class="inner">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="toggle">Technically any number of nested elements</a>
          <ul class="inner">
            <li>
              <a href="#" class="toggle">Another nested element</a>
              <div class="inner">
                <p>
                  As long as the inner element has inner as one of its classes then it will be toggled.
                </p>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus placerat fringilla. Duis a elit et dolor laoreet volutpat. Aliquam ultrices mauris id mattis imperdiet. Aenean cursus ultrices justo et varius. Suspendisse aliquam orci id dui dapibus
                  blandit. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed risus velit, pellentesque eu enim ac, ultricies pretium felis.
                </p>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>Option 2</li>

        <li>Option 3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your style is scss (sass), so it does not work. You need to transpile it in css.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.1em;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

.description {
  margin: 1em auto 2.25em;
}

body {
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 300px;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 1.5em auto;
  color: #333;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}
ul .inner {
  padding-left: 1em;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}
ul .inner.show {
  /*display: block;*/
}
ul li {
  margin: .5em 0;
}
ul li a.toggle {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.78);
  color: #fefefe;
  padding: .75em;
  border-radius: 0.15em;
  transition: background .3s ease;
}
ul li a.toggle:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
}
```